# Как выбрать из строки символ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая строка **img/page1/item1.jpg** а также такая **img/page1/item10.jpg**

Как получить из них **item1** и **item10** или хотя бы цифры после **item**

Comment: Чтобы получить цифры /(?<=item)(\d+)/g

Comment: Чтобы получить имя - 'img/page1/item101.jpg'.match(/(item)\w+/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let pathFile = 'img/page1/item10.jpg';
let treePath = pathFile.split('/');
let fileName = treePath[treePath.length-1];
console.log(fileName);
console.log(fileName.split('.')[0]);
```